# How to find rows in df2 which are not available in df1?

Tags: pyspark

How I can find the complement of a dataframe with respect of another dataframe?
In pandas it can be done by the following code:

```py
df = df1.merge(df2, how = 'outer' ,indicator=True).loc[lambda x : x['_merge']=='right_only']
```

Example:

```
+---------+----+
|     City|Temp|
+---------+----+
| New York|  59|
|  Chicago|  29|
|    Tokyo|  73|
|    Paris|  56|
|New Delhi|  48|
+---------+----+

+---------+----+
|     City|Temp|
+---------+----+
|   London|  55|
| New York|  55|
|    Tokyo|  73|
|New Delhi|  85|
|    Paris|  56|
+---------+----+
```

Result:

```
+---------+----+----------+
|     City|Temp|_merge    |
+---------+----+----------+
|   London|  55|right_only|
|New Delhi|  85|right_only|
| New York|  55|right_only|
+---------+----+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [subtract](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.subtract.html).

```py
df = df2.subtract(df1)
```

Result

```
+---------+----+
|     City|Temp|
+---------+----+
| New York|  55|
|   London|  55|
|New Delhi|  85|
+---------+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

`df1.join(df2, ['City', 'Temp'], 'outer').filter(" id1 IS NULL ")`

```
dt1 = [
    (0, 'New York',  59),
    (1, 'Chicago',   29),
    (2, 'Tokyo',     73),
    (3, 'Paris',     56),
    (4, 'New Delhi', 48),
]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(dt1, ['id1','City', 'Temp'])

dt2 = [
    (0, 'London',    55),
    (1, 'New York',  55),
    (2, 'Tokyo',     73),
    (3, 'New Delhi', 85),
    (4, 'Paris',     56),
]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(dt2, ['id2','City', 'Temp'])

(
    df1.join(df2, ['City', 'Temp'], 'outer')
        .filter(" id1 IS NULL ")
    .sort('id2')
        .show(10, False)
)

# +---------+----+----+---+
# |City     |Temp|id1 |id2|
# +---------+----+----+---+
# |London   |55  |null|0  |
# |New York |55  |null|1  |
# |New Delhi|85  |null|3  |
# +---------+----+----+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try "left_anti" join. Its Venn diagram looks like this:

[image]

And the code would look like this:

```
df = (
    df2
    .join(df1, ['City', 'Temp'], 'left_anti')
)
```

output:

```
+---------+----+
|     City|Temp|
+---------+----+
|   London|  55|
|New Delhi|  85|
| New York|  55|
+---------+----+
```